# {0,1} as function type in Isabelle

Tags: isabelle

I'm trying to write a function that takes a second parameter that can be either 0 or 1:

```
typedef f_2 = "{0::nat,1}"

function proj_add :: "(real × real) × f_2 ⇒ (real × real) × f_2 ⇒ (real × real) × f_2" where
  "proj_add ((x1,y1),l) ((x2,y2),j) = ((add (x1,y1) (x2,y2)), (l+j) mod 2)" 
    if "delta x1 y1 x2 y2 ≠ 0"
| "proj_add ((x1,y1),l) ((x2,y2),j) = ((ext_add (x1,y1) (x2,y2)), (l+j) mod 2)" 
    if "delta' x1 y1 x2 y2 ≠ 0"
```

If I write directly `{0::nat,1}` I get the error inner syntax error.

If I write `f_2` I get the error undefined type name f_2.

What is the right way to write this definition in Isabelle?

Comment: I can think of several options, but it is difficult to say what is the best option without knowing how the function will be used. 1). Use booleans instead of nat and apply conversion before and after the function application; 2). Use plain `nat` and worry about the input only in the theorems that you prove about the behaviour of the function; 3). Use one of the numeral types from `HOL-Library.Numeral_Type` (e.g. `1::2`).

Comment: I can hardly understand why it is necessary to define a new type constructor for this application. Nevertheless, of course, if you decide to do so, you need to prove the goal discharged by the command `typedef` before you can use it: `typedef f_2 = "{0::nat,1}" by auto`. However, in this case, you will also need to provide the infrastructure for it (e.g. define addition, multiplication, etc) - take a look at the theories `Nat` and `Int` from the main library to get an idea about how this can be achieved.

Comment: @xanonec you just gave me a very good idea with booleans i will try that for the moment, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the type `bit` in the theory `HOL-Library.Bit` with the two elements `0` and `1`. This contains all the setup that's needed to make the `0` and `1` notation work for `bit`s including pattern matching.